# CountDistinct based on a condition in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the below dataframe with me .

```
 +-------+---+----+
|Company|EMP|Flag|
+-------+---+----+
|      M| c1|   Y|
|      M| c1|   Y|
|      M| c2|   N|
|      M| c2|   N|
|      M| c3|   Y|
|      M| c3|   Y|
|      M| c4|   N|
|      M| c4|   N|
|      M| c5|   Y|
|      M| c5|   Y|
|      M| c6|   Y|
+-------+---+----+
```

Created by -

```
val df1=Seq(
("M","c1","Y"),
("M","c1","Y"),
("M","c2","N"),
("M","c2","N"),
("M","c3","Y"),
("M","c3","Y"),
("M","c4","N"),
("M","c4","N"),
("M","c5","Y"),
("M","c5","Y"),
("M","c6","Y")
)toDF("Company","EMP","Flag")
```

How can I take the distinct count EMP when FLAG =Y and FLAG = N. Once, an EMP has got a flag, it wont change again.I can achieve this with distinct. But is there any way to achive this without distinct(this is to avoid an extra join in the code)

Expected Output :

```
+---+---+---+---------+----------+
|  M|  Y|  N|Total_ROWs|Unique_Emp|
+---+---+---+---------+----------+
|  M|  4|  2|       11|         6|
+---+---+---+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
df1.groupBy("Company", "EMP", "Flag")
   .agg(count("Company").as("Row"))
   .groupBy("Company", "EMP", "Flag")
   .agg(count("Flag").as("YN"), sum("Row").as("Row"))
   .groupBy("Company")
   .agg(count(when($"Flag" === "Y", 1)).as("Y"), count(when($"Flag" === "N", 1)).as("N"), sum("Row").as("Total_ROWs"), count("EMP").as("Unique_EMP"))
   .show

+-------+---+---+----------+----------+
|Company|  Y|  N|Total_ROWs|Unique_EMP|
+-------+---+---+----------+----------+
|      M|  4|  2|        11|         6|
+-------+---+---+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Could you please help with - unboundedPreceding . Is this mandatory ?

Comment: Might be, I have tried with max or last but with the first window, it only found the value until the current row.

Comment: Sorry!! I think I did not post my question properly. I have edited it.

Comment: Hi @Lamanus , Sorry for the late reply as I was in another emergency and could not check this. This perfectly helps. Thanks :)